# Formatting time in user's timezone with moment.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, momentjs

I am having some trouble with the combination on PhantomJS and Moment.js. I would like to format a unix timestamp e.g. `1399089600000` in user's timezone in PhantomJS. However, I see some weird behavior. My machine timezone is `Asia/Hong_Kong` (UTC+8).

Below are ran in PhantomJS with env var `TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong`

```
var moment = require('moment.js');
moment(1399089600000).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-03 04:00:00 +00:00" which is ok
moment(1399089600000).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-04 05:00:00 +25:00" why +25?
moment(1399089600000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-04 05:00:00 +25:00" why +25?
```

When `TZ=UTC`

```
moment(1399089600000).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-03 04:00:00 +00:00" which is ok
moment(1399089600000).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-04 04:00:00 +24:00" why +24?
moment(1399089600000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-04 04:00:00 +24:00" why +24?
```

When `TZ` is not set, things seem to be fine,

```
moment(1399089600000).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-03 04:00:00 +00:00" which is ok
moment(1399089600000).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-03 12:00:00 +08:00" which is ok
moment(1399089600000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
// "2014-05-03 12:00:00 +08:00" which is ok
```

PhantomJS 2.1.1 and Moment.js 2.17.1 are used.

Thanks.

**Update**

When `TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong`, `moment(1399089600000).utcOffset()` = 1500

When `TZ=UTC`, `moment(1399089600000).utcOffset()` = 1440

When `TZ=`, `moment(1399089600000).utcOffset()` = 480

Comment: Out of interest, are you using `moment-timezone` ?

Comment: No, I'm not using moment-timezone. I read somewhere that UTC and local time zone can be handled by `moment` alone.

Comment: What is the value of `moment(1399089600000).utcOffset()` in the three scenarios? Maybe you simply do not have to set `TZ` env var.

Comment: @VincenzoC Updated the question with the extra info you asked for, I need to set TZ explicitly since it is for some tests which run on environments in different timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out PhantomJS does not play well with Windows when it comes to the `TZ` environment variable.

Taking `momentjs` out of the equation:

In a Windows machine:

When `TZ=UTC`, `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` returns `-1440` which is wrong.

But in a Linux machine (Ubuntu when I tested):

When `TZ=UTC`, `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` returns `0` which is correct.

I tested other variations of `TZ` values on Linux and they are all correct.